# Translating Stata code to R (creating flags and new variables) using ACS PUMS data

Tags: r, stata, demographics

I have the following Stata code that I am needing to translate over to R (this code uses the 2019 5-year ACS PUMS file):

```
/*Create a flag to identify workers in the household*/
gen worker=(wkl=="1")
replace worker=. if wkl==""

/*Generate a variable representing number of workers in the household*/
by serialno, sort: egen wihh=sum(worker)
```

Where I am coming up blank is in the following places:

1. How do I tell R to create a flag? I presume this is different than creating a new variable? and
2. Generating a variable using SERIALNO and sorting by a new variable (WIHH) using a sum function referring to the number of worker flag previously created.

For example, I can create a new variable using:

```
2019PUMS$worker <- recode(2019PUMS$WKL, recodes = "1=1, else = NA", as.factor = T)
```

However, I believe that this only creates a new variable here and I presume this is not the same as creating a flag.

Comment: The Stata code here is just asking for a count of how often `wk1` is 1 for each distinct serial number. (The `replace` statement is quite unneeded and indeed not good style at all.)   I am positive about Stata but to get a good R answer directly,  which is what you want, just show how the data are held in R and explain what you want to calculate. Don't ask about translation from one language to another if the problem can be stated simply as how to do something in R.

Comment: Similarly, for every R person who knows about ACS PUMS data, there are probably hundreds more who can answer a question if you just explain what the data look like,

Answer (score 0):

The following Stata code creates a variable called `worker` if the existing variable `wkl` is equal to `"1"` and equal to missing if if the value of `wkl` equals `""`.

```
gen worker=(wkl=="1")
replace worker=. if wkl==""
```

With a dataframe called `df` holding your data, the following would do the same:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
    mutate(worker = ifelse(wkl == "1", 1, ifelse(wkl != "", 0, NA)))
```

The code below instructs Stata to generate the number of workers in the household (which is indexed, I believe, by the variable `serialno`):

```
/*Generate a variable representing number of workers in the household*/
by serialno, sort: egen wihh=sum(worker)
```

To do this in R, you would use the following:

```r
df <- df %>%
    group_by(serialno) %>%
    mutate(wihh = sum(worker))
```

The "flag" is simply a variable that takes on values of 1 or 0 (if the condition is true or false, respectively). The R code above does the same thing. (In R you can also create flags that take on the boolean values `TRUE`/`FALSE` rather than 1/0 if you desire.)